# How to read and run algorithm in multiple images at different directories?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops, computer-vision

I've been working on a segmentation algorithm (mean-shift). The biggest problem is related to the images. They are huge and have hundreds of objects.
This algorithm is powerful but at the same time it's computationally intensive. 
All of this to say that each image takes at least 1 hour to segment and I have 150 images.

I'm working all day and would like to run this algorithm during daytime and not worry about run the algorithm for each individual image. And at the same time save the result in the same folder.

I have the images in a directory, like this:

```
C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/0001/0001.png
C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/0002/0002.png
C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/0003/0003.png
...
```

And I read the image like this:
`I=imread('C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/0001/0001.png')`

Comment: Where would the 2nd/3rd/... image be stored?

Comment: Sorry Forgot to wright that. They are like this: C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/0002/0002.png   C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/0003/003.png

Comment: Please update your question with that

Comment: So is the result another image file? And you want the result for image `0001.png` to be in the same folder as `0001.png`, right?

Comment: Yah its another image file in the same folder. It could be something like `r0001.png´

Comment: I gave you 2 solutions, I suggest the primary one though since it's smaller and more compact. Let me know if it works for you and kindly accept if it does :D

Comment: Thanks a lot  @krisdestruction! I've tried but unfortunately it didn't worked. i got this error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. Probably it is something that i'm doing it wrong! :) I will took a better look. But thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: @John Which method did you use? Does it work for my toy example? Which line does it error out at?

Comment: To try your code i used in some sample code that i have. Using Hough Transform to find circular objects. It fails in my imfilter function. `W = fspecial('gaussian',[10,10]);
J = imfilter(I{i},W);
X = rgb2gray(J);

% Finding Circular objects -- Houng Transform
[centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(X,[10 20], 'Sensitivity',0.92,'Edge',0.03); 
centersStrong = centers(1:60,:);
radiiStrong = radii(1:60);
metricStrong = metric(1:60);
viscircles(centersStrong, radiiStrong,'EdgeColor','r');`

Comment: Hmm did you assign a value to `i`? `i` is a variable, just substitute a number to it, or put it into a loop to do stuff

Comment: Please check my answer again. You can get the first element using `I{1}`.

Comment: @ krisdestruction It worked like that. Thanks!  One more thing! Do you know how can i save the result in the same folder that i read the image? I would like to do something like this : `F = cellfun( @(b) imwrite( ['C:/Folder1/Folder2/' b '/'result_b '.png'] ), B, 'UniformOutput', false );`

Comment: I've tried like this also and it doesent work :( `b = sprintf( '%04d', i );
imwrite( ['C:/Folder1/Folder2//Folder3' b '/' b '_result.png'] );`

Answer (score 1):

First create the vector 1-150 indexing the images.

```
a = 1:150;
```

**Primary Solution**

Now here's a 1 liner that should do it for you.

```
A = arrayfun( @(x) sprintf( '%04d', x ), a, 'UniformOutput', false );
I = cellfun( @(b) imread( ['C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/' b '/' b '.png'] ), A, 'UniformOutput', false );
```

The `arrayfun` line will pad the vector a with zeros and turn it into a cell of strings. The `cellfun` line will perform the imread operation and store it into the matrix I.

You can then access each image using `I{i}`.

**Alternate Loop Solution**

The create a cell for the images.

```
I = cell(1,length(a));
```

Then create a loop that will prepad the index. Then call imread

```
for i = a
    b = sprintf( '%04d', i );
    I{i} = imread( ['C: Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/' b '/' b '.png'] );
end
```

You can then access each image using `I{1}` for the first element. For reference, this is the value of each b when running the loop.

```
b =
0001
b =
0002
b =
0003
...
```